# MS SQL to MySQL using MySQL Migration Toolkit: permission issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I have a MS SQL imported into SQL Server 2008 from a .bak and I set it to Mixed mode. I have a SQL user (called "test") that can correctly access the database using SQL Server.

I need to convert this to a MySQL database, so I got the MySQL Migration Toolkit. I pick "MS SQL Server" and then it asks for the hostname/username/password/database. I'm not 100% sure on these, but I used "localhost" (running on same computer), left the port as is (1433) and the username/password ("test") for the SQL Server. And I used the database name for the SQL Server database I'm looking to import. I clicked next, enter my MySQL database details and then attempt to run it and I get this error:

```
Connecting to source database and retrieve schemata names.
Initializing JDBC driver ... 
Driver class MS SQL JDBC Driver
Opening connection ... 
Connection jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/Orders;user=test;password=blah;charset=utf-8;domain=
The list of schema names could not be retrieved (error: 0).
ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata :Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
Details: 
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:372)
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:178)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringGeneric.establishConnection(ReverseEngineeringGeneric.java:141)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata(ReverseEngineeringMssql.java:99)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.Grt.callModuleFunction(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not familiar with MS SQL that much, but I can login and access this database with the "test" user just fine in MS SQL. So I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like some of the sql server services aren't running.  In particular sql browser.  Move this to serverfault.com for better help.

Comment: Forgot to enable TCP connections in the MSSQL config, yep.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO instead of localhost better use 127.0.0.1.
And need check if connection throw TCP abilitated
Also need check firewall.